# FastAPI/uvicorn workers printing additional prints

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, multiprocessing, fastapi

I am using FastAPI and have a print statement `print("Initializing app...")` at the top of my script (just after the imports). This is how I am running the app (in the script itself) -

`uvicorn.run("app:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=9090, workers=4)`

Here, I have mentioned 4 workers. So, I expect 4 times `Initializing app...` being printed when I run the application.

But it is printing 9 times -

[image: Logs]

I am not able to understand the additional `Initializing app...` being printed.

Am I missing something?

Comment: try to disable hot reloading with `--no-reload`

Comment: I found out one parameter `reload` which can be used as 
`uvicorn.run("app:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=9090, workers=4, reload=False)`
But still same issue.
Turns out `reload` is by default `False`only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discrepancy in the number of times `"Initializing app..."` is being printed may be explained by the way FastAPI and ASGI (Asynchronous Server Gateway Interface) work with multiple workers in combination with the uvicorn server.

When you specify multiple workers using `uvicorn`, you are essentially running multiple instances of your FastAPI application, each in its own process. This is done to enable concurrent handling of incoming requests and to take advantage of multi-core processors.

However, it's important to note that the top-level code in your script is executed once for each worker. This means that the code outside of FastAPI routes, like your `print("Initializing app...")` statement, will also be executed once for each worker.

In your case, you specified 4 workers, which is why you see `"Initializing app..."` printed maybe the first 4 times, but you're also seeing additional prints invoked due to how ASGI and uvicorn might be parallelizing the code. This maybe why you see a total of 9 prints instead of 4. The exact number of additional prints can vary depending on how uvicorn manages its worker processes on any machine depending on where you are running this script.

If you want to execute something only once for the entire application startup per core, you can use [FastAPI's lifespan events](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#lifespan)

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this, say you have a file called `main.py` that has a variable called `app` where `FastAPI(...)` class object is defined.

```py
# main.py

import uvicorn

from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from fastapi import FastAPI


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # Steps that will be performed on startup events only once.
    print("Initializing app...")
    yield
    # Steps that will happen on shutdown event


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=9090, workers=4)
```

With this modification, `"Initializing app..."` will be printed only once during the startup of your FastAPI application. i.e. with 4 workers you will see the startup event statements be executed only 4 times:

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:9090 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started parent process [17895]
Initializing app...
Initializing app...
Initializing app...
Initializing app...
INFO:     Started server process [17897]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Started server process [17898]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Started server process [17900]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Started server process [17899]
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Finished server process [17897]
INFO:     Finished server process [17898]
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Finished server process [17900]
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Finished server process [17899]
INFO:     Stopping parent process [17895]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This worked! Thank you..  But I am still not able to understand why 9 prints? It does parallelization, it should ideally print just 4 prints as 4 workers are active and running?

Comment: Awesome!! and yes if you were to think of a multiprocessing library parallelizing the whole script onto 4 cores, it should have only executed 4 prints. However, since Fast API is executed differently given it is an ASGI server under the hood you are more likely parallelizing the routes instead to allow for concurrency in which case everything happening outside of the route methods is now being attached to each endpoint that is then parallelized. Hopefully [this post](https://dev.to/horaceg/concurrency-in-python-with-fastapi-222f) points you to more insights into this.